# Code works on NodeMCU 1.0 but not on ESP8266 12E

Tags: arduino, gps, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a NodeMCU 1.0 and a ESP8266 12-E I created some code to check a GPS signal and report back, on the NodeMCU the code works 100% no problems but when I load the code on a ESP8266 12-e (with NodeMCU flashed on it) I can not get the GPS signal to show up wired to the same GPOI ports and everything.

Most of the code:

```
#include   <TimGPS.h>            
#include   <SoftwareSerial.h > 
#include "FS.h"
extern "C" { 
 #include "gpio.h" 
 #include "user_interface.h" 
} 
static const int RXPin = 12, TXPin = 255; 
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
TimGPS gps;  
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin); 
void printGPSData()
{
  Serial.print("Latitude  : ");
  Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);
  Serial.print("Longitude : ");
  Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
  Serial.print("Speed : ");
  Serial.println(gps.speed.mph(), 6);
  Serial.print("Satellites: ");
  Serial.println(gps.satellites.value());
  Serial.print("Time UTC  : ");
  Serial.print(gps.time.hour());                        
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(gps.time.minute());                     
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(gps.time.second());
}

static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)                
{
 unsigned long start = millis();
 do 
 {
   while (ss.available())
     gps.encode(ss.read());
 } while (millis() - start < ms);
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println("Startup");
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}
void loop() {
if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10) {
      Serial.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));
    }
    else
    {
        printGPSData(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about [NodeMCU v1/0.9 or v2/1.0](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/)? One's got an ESP-12 and the other's got an ESP-12E.

Comment: V2 with the ESP 12-E

Comment: Ok, I clarified that in your title. However, I'm still confused...you're showing Arduino code but you also state you had a device "with NodeMCU flashed on it".

Comment: Correct you can run Arduino code on a NodeMCU

Comment: Really? No seriously, I do know that (I'm a NodeMCU firmware committer) but your description is confusing. The fact that the NodeMCU _firmware_ was flashed to the NodeMCU _devkit_ doesn't have anything to do with the problem, does it? I added the 'arduino' tag to this question early on to attract the correct audience here.

Comment: Ahh ok the confusion is on the NodeMCU devkit it works when I take a ESP8266 12-e (just the board) and then flash it with NodeMCU and run the same code it does not work.

Comment: Why would you flash the NodeMCU firmware if you want to run Arduino code? At the risk of sounding silly for stating the obvious...to use the NodeMCU firmware you have to write Lua (script) code and upload it. To use the Arduino platform you write Arduino code, compile it and flash that to the device.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you aware that the NodeMCU devkit/hardware PIN numbering is different from 'plain' ESP8266 (12) modules?

Comment: And also to make sure, you say you cannot get a GPS signal, am I correct in assuming that the code does show it runs, you see "Startup" and No GPS data received: check wiring" on the serial port?

Comment: Yes the pinout is different, and I have changed the pins to the correct placement on the NodeMCU.. Yes the serial port shows No GPS data received: check wiring. what is odd is once and while I will see the atomic clock time but its off but lat and lon all zeros